# Why are my RSI values different than Yahoo Finance

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, yahoo-finance, quantitative-finance

I tried calculating RSI in both SMA and EMA method using the following code.

```
def rsi(data, period = 14, column = 'Close'):
  delta = data[column].diff()
  delta = delta[1:]
  up = delta.clip(lower=0)
  down = delta.clip(upper=0)
  up[ up < 0 ] = 0
  down[down > 0] = 0
  data['UP'] = up
  data['DOWN'] = down
  
  # Calculate the EWMA
  roll_up1 = up.ewm(span=period).mean()
  roll_down1 = down.abs().ewm(span=period).mean()

  # Calculate the RSI based on EWMA
  RS1 = roll_up1 / roll_down1
  RSI1 = 100.0 - (100.0 / (1.0 + RS1))

  # Calculate the SMA
  roll_up2 = up.rolling(period).mean()
  roll_down2 = down.abs().rolling(period).mean()

  # Calculate the RSI based on SMA
  RS2 = roll_up2 / roll_down2
  RSI2 = 100.0 - (100.0 / (1.0 + RS2))

  data['RSI1'] = RSI1
  data['RSI2'] = RSI2


  return data
```

Then I tried calculating RSI for AAPL stock

```
df = yf.download('AAPL', period="3d", interval = '1h')
rsi(df)
df = df.dropna()
df
```

The results were like the following,

```
                            Close       RSI1        RSI2
2021-06-18 09:30:00-04:00   131.050003  46.782703   53.072098
2021-06-18 10:30:00-04:00   130.327499  37.694286   48.587796
2021-06-18 11:30:00-04:00   130.990005  48.317262   55.852004
2021-06-18 12:30:00-04:00   130.809998  45.865629   53.151575
2021-06-18 13:30:00-04:00   130.960007  48.383954   61.052606
2021-06-18 14:30:00-04:00   130.904999  47.449990   55.294624
2021-06-18 15:30:00-04:00   130.399994  39.394643   51.816916
```

But when I checked Yahoo Finance chart,

The RSI value is close to the SMA method. But still different.

```
                            Close       RSI
2021-06-18 13:30:00-04:00   130.960007  49.04
2021-06-18 14:30:00-04:00   130.904999  48.35
2021-06-18 15:30:00-04:00   130.399994  42.46
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find out why you have different results?

Answer (score 1):

All the code you posted was correct, except that you need to EWMA.

What you need to change is the following line:

```
 # Calculate the EWMA
 adjust: bool = False
 ignore_na: bool = True

roll_up1 = up.ewm(alpha=(1.0 / period), adjust=adjust, ignore_na=ignore_na, min_periods=period).mean()
roll_down1 = down.abs().ewm(alpha=(1.0 / period), adjust=adjust, ignore_na=ignore_na, min_periods=period).mean()
```

And then finally, RSI is calculated with:

```
 RSI = 100.0 * roll_up1 / (roll_down1 + roll_down1 )
```